# hamburger menu always shows, even on desktop

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

In my bootstrap navbar, there is a menu button that appears when the screen gets too small and if you are on mobile.
It works fine, but the menu button always shows. Even when you are on a Desktop in full screen, there is a menu button and the menu items.
On mobile, the menu items only show when you click menu so that's fine.

I tried moving the menu items to the right when they show, and that works just fine but after that, the menu button always shows.

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top bg-inverse" id="mainNav">
    
        <div class="bubbel mr-auto bg-light">
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
                <img src="img/timmerbedrijfvlot-transparant.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-nav">
            </a>
        </div>
        <button class="navbar-uppercase bg-dark text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
            Menu
            <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
            <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto  float-right text-right pr-3">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    
    </nav>
```

Comment: I tried your code, with few includes, and it works. Make sure you include all required JS files.

Comment: @AlmirHusić In a fiddle there seems to be an issue

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the class `navbar-toggler` to your button.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg  fixed-top bg-inverse" id="mainNav">

    <div class="bubbel mr-auto bg-light">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">
            <img src="img/timmerbedrijfvlot-transparant.png" alt="Logo" class="logo-nav">
        </a>
    </div>
    <button class="navbar-toggler navbar-uppercase bg-dark text-white rounded" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navbarResponsive" aria-controls="navbarResponsive" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
        Menu
        <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
    </button>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarResponsive">
        <ul class="navbar-nav ml-auto  float-right text-right pr-3">
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#section1">Section 1</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#section2">Section 2</a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
                <a class="nav-link text-dark" href="#section3">Section 3</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</nav>
```

Comment: I have another question... i am trying to get the hamburger menu on the right side when the page gets smaller, now it sticks to the left side of the page

Comment: You can try something like this `@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) { button.navbar-toggler { float: right; }}`